# Reputable source of learning greenhouse practices, specifically for microgreens?

Tags: growth, greenhouse

I am allowed to use my school's greenhouse and have some space allotted to me. I want to start growing microgreens, but most of the videos and sources I read are always trying to "sell" me something. **Is there any reputable site (free to access) that has this information on yielding microgreens or just general microgreen-like plant rearing in a greenhouse environment?** I am a bit out of my element since I have not frequented the greenhouse much, and like to prime myself before asking friends / teachers.

Comment: Ro Siv...you could even call this guy!!  He works with greenhouses in the college environment as well as his own...community owned/education greenhouses.  Look his number up...I do have his book but have to check it out at the library as a reference (super by the way).  Think he is in the...Georgia area?  Can't remember.  Look him up on the internet and he'll probably have his email address...he'd LOVE to help you!  This is right up his 'alley' with education!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're googling how to grow microgreens in a greenhouse, you will likely get a lot of sales and information of the type you're complaining about, or information aimed at large professional growers. The other problem you might have is that any 'controlled conditions' mentioned as suitable for this type of crop may not be the same conditions created for growing other people's crops in a shared greenhouse. However, I'm having the same difficulty you're having in finding out what the 'controlled conditions' in a greenhouse might be for microgreens.

Microgreens can be easily grown on a sunny kitchen windowsill or outdoors, and anyone growing in greenhouses is usually a commercial producer, or a small producer growing for sale, so that's why its difficult to find the information you want. Maybe you can adapt the methods in the links below to the greenhouse space you've been allotted:

http://www.gardeners.com/how-to/how-to-grow-microgreens/7987.html

http://www.rodalesorganiclife.com/garden/growing-microgreens-indoors

Note there is a requirement for a minimum of 4 hours filtered sunlight or very bright daylight per day, or artificial gro lights, so the space you've been allocated in the greenhouse needs to be appropriate for this.

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo's answer is very good!  The best book I've got in my library that I turn to so very often is by SHANE SMITH...super for just learning about gardening in general but couldn't have found a better source.  I think the book is called 'Green House Gardening'...or close.

Comment: I was hoping for a online source that I could go to. I doubt my local library has it.  Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry...I love books.  The internet, I am on it an awful lot, doesn't take the place of books for me...SO much work, ads, misdirection!!  Look Shane Smith up on the internet!  I have read many books on greenhouses and this guy was my absolute favorite!  He is nuts and bolts and so very readable!!  My library in PODUNK, USA...has it!!  And you know that libraries are interconnected...right?  As well as on the internet!  When one reads an entire book/s on one guy you get a feel for the overall picture of the author's knowledge.  You'll love this guy...